# What is the best way to bypass Wordpress's HTML sanitization so I can use bootstrap html in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get on developing websites on Wordpress for easier management for the future admins.

I have created a bootstrap theme on my own. I got all the pages smoothly into Wordpress and are now easy to edit. However I have this one page which has tables, buttons, glyphicons and once I click the "graphic" view while editing the page it breaks it.

So I was thinking that that won't do and I decided to create a new plugin to fix this problem. A simple plugin which has few textboxes on the admin settings page and then just prints the texts on the page where I want them to go.

However I tried to look for tutorials and I'm just overwhelmed. I have gotten my plugin to work somewhat. It has a admin setup page and it can print customized text to a page where my shortcode is. [Thanks to this post!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795445/how-to-write-a-wordpress-plugin)

However, I still don't know what to do from this point on.

My question is: Could you help me by giving me an example code to get the same kind of textbox to my plugin's admin page as I have while editing/adding new pages (with graphic view) which saves the text and displays it on a page.

I have no idea if this is the way to go but I can't think of anything else right now. I was thinking that the settings page has a couple of textboxes and the text in them goes where I want it to go on a page. So the future admin won't see the unnecessary html code and therefore can't break it.

Comment: So you have html that doesn't work correctly when you paste it into the WYSIWYG editor in Wordpress and you want to know how to store that text in Wordpress and then retreive it and display it on a page without any of the original html getting changed?  Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: could you please provide a minimal example of html you are putting on post content that breaks?

Comment: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>`
Wordpress removes the span inside the buttons and so I have no icons in the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would abandon the "plugin" idea.  There are several more elegant ways to do this besides writing a plugin.

By far the easiest to implement is this:
 1.  Store the html in a "Custom Field" https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields
 2.  Display the contents in your page (or post) template  https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Displaying_Custom_Fields

Comment: Thank you! This was pretty much what I was looking for. I also found this plugin called "Advanced Custom Fields" which I can use to customize the custom fields to be more user friendly. You made my day!

Comment: Yes.  ACF is terrific.  I originally suggested that as a second option but I figured I'd keep it simple.